# Inserir dados em mysql, commit() não resulta

Tags: mysql, python, sql-insert

Eu queria inserir na Base de dados definitivamente. Mas com este código eu não estou a conseguir, o registo é guardado mas não faz o `commit()`:

```
import MySQLdb

def conn():
  try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="",db="yoo")
    return db
  except:
    exit("sorry can't connect")

def insert(cur, names):
  try:
    for i in names:
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (person) VALUES (%s)", str(i))
    conn().commit() #write up in DB definitly
    return "success"
  except:
    return "Something went wrong with the insertion"

def main():
  conn()
  cur = conn().cursor()

  numOfNames = int(raw_input("how many names?\n"))
  names = []

  for i in range(numOfNames):
    name = raw_input("Insert a name\n")
    names.append(name)

  print insert(cur, names)

main()
```

Comment: não teria que ser cur.commit()?

Comment: Segundo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/how-can-i-insert-data-into-a-mysql-database, acho que não

Comment: humm. Também não resulta. Mas porque é que haveria de perder a referência?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acredito que seja porque é perdido a referencia da variável que esta sendo tratada, tente assim ve se da

```
import MySQLdb

def conn():
  try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="",db="yoo")
    return db
  except:
    exit("sorry can't connect")

def insert(db, names):
  try:
    for i in names:
      db.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO test (person) VALUES (%s)", str(i))
    db.commit() #write up in DB definitly
    return "success"
  except:
    return "Something went wrong with the insertion"

def main():
  db = conn()

  numOfNames = int(raw_input("how many names?\n"))
  names = []

  for i in range(numOfNames):
    name = raw_input("Insert a name\n")
    names.append(name)

  print insert(db, names)

main()
```

Comment: Muito obgado, resultou, eu não tinha chegado lá. Não percebo porque perde a referencia, mas isto foi uma boa maneira de contornar isso

Comment: pq toda vez que vc chama conn() ele abre uma nova conexao e cada conexao tem seu cursor, vc criar um cursor em uma conexaoo e cria outra conexao para dar o commit mas no cursor dela nao tem nada

Comment: Haa... Ok já compreendi